# How to free memory with python garbage collection with list

Tags: python

I have a python process with a loop :

```
for i in range(1, 100000) :
    vv = get_biglist( 10000 )
    ....
```

For some reasons, interpreter memory
keeps increasing.

Is there a way to contain memory size or to free
memory to the OS ?

Comment: which version of Python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: python 3 is the version. Can we use subprocess or concurrent futures ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to print (or do anything actually) with a large data set's objects, you should probably use generators, which are runtime iterators which iterate over the iterable objects dynamically and are therefore suited to the task of going over very large data sets. What you could do might be something like this:

```
def generator(l):
    for i in l:
        yield i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    very_large_list = [1,2,3]
    for i in generator(very_large_list):    # Iterate over the list dynamically without storing in memory
        print i
```